# CSS columns issues

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a basic web page because I'm just starting coding in HTML and CSS, and some issues came up...

I'm doing a basic web page with a header, 3 columns and a footer. Everything works nice, except for the third column: it is on the first one, and I don't even know how to fix that.

HTML STUFF:

http://pastebin.com/vvg1LSiz

And here is my CSS stuff:

http://pastebin.com/dSN83Bs6

Comment: have you heard about: jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Add relevant code to the question itself, please. And make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the following for you to note:

- your right and left columns are not contained inside the content-wrapper.
- you force margin the left-column too much after the change of moving them inside the content-wrapper div
- you didn't put a width for the content-column in the middle
- your margin is unnecessary for the left and right column
- right column should be float right, not float left

Here is the updated changes:
*Note: sorry for the style not being in a separate style sheet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Teste</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style>
/* CSS Document */

body{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        line-height: 1.3em;
}

#wrapper{
        width: 1120px;
        margin: 0 auto;
}

#headerdiv{
        background: #000;
        height: 90px;
}

#headerdiv h1{
        margin: 0;
        padding-top: 15px;
        color: #C30;
}

#content-wrapper{
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
}

#content-column{
        padding: 10px 5px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 600px;
        border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #D4D4D4;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -0.9px 5px #D4D4D4;
}

#left-column{
        padding: 10px 5px;
        float: left;
        width: 235px;
       margin: 0;
        background: #FFF;
}

#right-column{
        padding: 10px 5px;
        float: right;
        width: 235px;
        margin-left: 0;
        background: #FFF;
}

#footer{
        clear: left;
        width: 100%;
        background: black;
        color: #FFF;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 4px 0;
}

#footer a{
        color: #FFFF80;
}

.sidediv{
        margin: 10px;
        margin-top: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="headerdiv"><div class="sidediv"><h1>Um logo qualquer por aí</h1></div></div>

<div id="content-wrapper">
<div id="left-column">
<div class="sidediv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam eget ligula eu lectus lobortis condimentum. Aliquam nonummy auctor massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla at risus. Quisque purus magna, auctor et, sagittis ac, posuere eu, lectus. Nam mattis, felis ut adipiscing.</div>

</div>
<div id="right-column">
<div class="sidediv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam eget ligula eu lectus lobortis condimentum. Aliquam nonummy auctor massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla at risus. Quisque purus magna, auctor et, sagittis ac, posuere eu, lectus. Nam mattis, felis ut adipiscing.</div>
</div>
<div id="content-column">
<div class="sidediv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam eget ligula eu lectus lobortis condimentum. Aliquam nonummy auctor massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla at risus. Quisque purus magna, auctor et, sagittis ac, posuere eu, lectus. Nam mattis, felis ut adipiscing.</div>
</div>

</div>





<div id="footer">Oi, eu sou um footer! :D</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your **html** is like this:

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
    <div id="headerdiv"></div>
    <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div id="content-column"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="left-column"></div>
    <div id="right-column"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

you should **structure** it like **this**:

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
    <div id="headerdiv"></div>
    <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div id="left-column"></div>
        <div id="content-column"></div>
        <div id="right-column"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```